# In R, with 'httr' package, where do I use 'provider ID' to connect to an API with Oauth2.0?

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to connect to an API with Oauth2.0 to obtain data using R. The database owner gave me the following credentials:

- domain name: https://...
- providerID: 7
- client id: encoded string
- client secret: encoded string

I'm trying to use the 'httr' package but I can't find providerID in any of the documentation and I'm new to Oauth2.0. I don't know which step in the dance the providerID is used. Getting the token initially, or making the query after?

Besides the httr documentation, my main reference is this, which also doesn't mention provider ID.
https://blog.r-hub.io/2021/01/25/oauth-2.0/

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/oauth2.0_token.html ? They might go in the `credentials = ` within a list. They might also be set as a parameter in a URL query. It really depends on the API.

Comment: A colleague did manage to get a status 200, which is good news. He just added 'provider/7' to the get request. I'll mark it resolved in a few hours, hoping to see if anyone provides a more rigorous answer or good resource to read.  res <- GET("https://xxx/provider/7",
           config=config(token = toke))

Answer (score 0):

Credentials not documented in general API packages are probably API specific. Try setting them as a parameter in the URL query, or talk to the API creator.